# In member function errors c++

Tags: c++, derived-class

I am receiving some errors when compiling my code.

```
circleTypeImp.cpp: In member function âdouble circleType::getRadius() constâ:
circleTypeImp.cpp:10: error: argument of type âdouble (circleType::)()constâ does not match âdoubleâ
circleTypeImp.cpp: In member function âdouble circleType::setAreaCircle() constâ:
circleTypeImp.cpp:15: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the â&â ?)
circleTypeImp.cpp: In member function âdouble circleType::setCircumference() constâ:
circleTypeImp.cpp:20: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the â&â ?)
pointTypeImp.cpp: In member function âvoid pointType::setXCoordinate(double)â:
pointTypeImp.cpp:9: error: âxâ was not declared in this scope
pointTypeImp.cpp: In member function âvoid pointType::setYCoordinate(double)â:
pointTypeImp.cpp:14: error: âyâ was not declared in this scope
pointTypeImp.cpp: At global scope:
pointTypeImp.cpp:23: error: prototype for âdouble pointType::getXCoordinate(double)â does not match any in class âpointTypeâ
pointTypee.h:15: error: candidate is: double pointType::getXCoordinate() const
pointTypeImp.cpp:28: error: prototype for âdouble pointType::getYCoordinate(double)â does not match any in class âpointTypeâ
pointTypee.h:16: error: candidate is: double pointType::getYCoordinate() const
```

I have overlooked my code and I cant seem to see what is wrong with it. If someone could point it out to me what is needing to be done, I'd appreciate it. I am not looking for someone to do it for me, I am just needing some help figuring it out.

```
//main.cpp

#include "pointTypee.h"
#include "circleTypee.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    pointType p;
    circleType c;

    double rad;
    double area;
    double circum;


    double x;
    double y;

    cout << "Enter the x coordinate " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the y coordinate " << endl;
    cin >> y;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The X & Y coordinates are: (" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
    cout << "The area of the circle is: ";          //Add 
    cout << "The circumference of the circle is: "; //Add 

}


//PointType.cpp

#include "pointTypee.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 

void pointType::setXCoordinate (double xcoord)
{
    xcoord = x;
}

void pointType::setYCoordinate (double ycoord)
{
    ycoord= y;
}

void pointType::print() const
{
    cout << "The center point is at (" << xcoord << "," << ycoord << ")" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

double pointType::getXCoordinate(double xcoord)
{
    return xcoord;
}

double pointType::getYCoordinate(double ycoord)
{
    return ycoord;
}
pointType::pointType(double xcoord, double ycoord)
{
     xcoord=0;
     ycoord=0;

}



//pointType.h

#ifndef POINTTYPEE_H
#define POINTTYPEE_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class pointType
{
public:
    void print() const;
    void setXCoordinate(double xcoord);
    void setYCoordinate(double ycoord);
    double getXCoordinate() const;
    double getYCoordinate() const;
    pointType(void);
    pointType(double xcoord, double ycoord);
    ~pointType(void);

private:
    double xcoord;
    double ycoord;

};
#endif


//circleType.h

#ifndef CIRCLETYPEE_H
#define CIRCLETYPEE_H

#include "pointTypee.h"

class circleType : public pointType
{
public: 
    //circleType(double xcoord, double ycoord, double radius);
    void print() const;
    double setAreaCircle() const;
    double setCircumference() const;
    double getRadius() const;
    circleType(double xcoord, double ycoord, double radius);
    ~circleType(void);
    circleType();
    //virtual ~circleType();

private:
    double radius() const;
    static double pie;

};
#endif 



//circleTypeImp.cpp

#include "circleTypee.h"
#include "pointTypee.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

double circleType::getRadius()const
{
    return radius;
}

double circleType::setAreaCircle () const
{
    return 3.14 * radius * radius;
}

double circleType::setCircumference() const
{
    return 3.14 * 2 * radius;
}

circleType::circleType()
{
    //circleType::circleType();
}

circleType::~circleType()
{

}

double pie = 3.14;
```

Comment: Why would you assign to the parameters passed by value? And the hell are `getXCoordinate` etc. doing? Forget it, everything is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> circleTypeImp.cpp: In member function âdouble circleType::getRadius() constâ:
>   circleTypeImp.cpp:10: error: argument of type âdouble (circleType::)()constâ does not match âdoubleâ

```
private:
    double radius() const;
//...
return radius;
```

You return the member function `radius()`, which returns a double, but it is not a double. I would guess, you wanted a member `double radius;` instead.

> circleTypeImp.cpp: In member function âdouble circleType::setAreaCircle() constâ:
>   circleTypeImp.cpp:15: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the â&â ?)
>   circleTypeImp.cpp: In member function âdouble circleType::setCircumference() constâ:
>   circleTypeImp.cpp:20: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the â&â ?)

Same here, you use the member *function* `radius()`, which is not a double.

> pointTypeImp.cpp: In member function âvoid pointType::setXCoordinate(double)â:
>   pointTypeImp.cpp:9: error: âxâ was not declared in this scope
>   pointTypeImp.cpp: In member function âvoid pointType::setYCoordinate(double)â:
>   pointTypeImp.cpp:14: error: âyâ was not declared in this scope

```
void pointType::setXCoordinate (double xcoord)
{
    xcoord = x;
}

void pointType::setYCoordinate (double ycoord)
{
    ycoord= y;
}
```

The error says it already, neither `x` nor `y` is declared. This should be

```
void pointType::setXCoordinate (double x)
//...
void pointType::setYCoordinate (double y)
//...
```

> pointTypeImp.cpp: At global scope:
>   pointTypeImp.cpp:23: error: prototype for âdouble pointType::getXCoordinate(double)â does not match any in class âpointTypeâ
>   pointTypee.h:15: error: candidate is: double pointType::getXCoordinate() const

Mismatch between declaration and definition

```
double pointType::getXCoordinate() const
double pointType::getXCoordinate(double)
```

> pointTypeImp.cpp:28: error: prototype for âdouble pointType::getYCoordinate(double)â does not match any in class âpointTypeâ
>   pointTypee.h:16: error: candidate is: double pointType::getYCoordinate() const

Same here.